# How can I go with For Each over class properties in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, ienumerable

I see such C# code which allow me go with foreach cycle over class properties.

```
public class EstimateDetailsModel : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public string Dma { get; set; }

    public string Callsign { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Dma;
        yield return Callsign;
        yield return Description;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Help please. How can I make something like this using vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have provided here is a C# iterator method (the methods containing `yield return`).  Unfortunately there is no analogous feature for VB.Net at this time.  The easiest way to simulate this is to instead build up a `List(Of String)` and return thate

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerable(Of String) _ 
    Implements IEnumerable(Of String).GetEnumerator
  Dim list As New List(Of String)()
  list.Add(Dma)
  list.Add(Callsign)
  list.Add(Description)
  return list
End Function 

Public Function GetEnumerator2() As IEnumerable _ 
    Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
  Return GetEnumerator()
End Function
```

This isn't exactly equivalent to the C# version.  Mainly because it will be promptly executed instead of delayed executed.  But the end effect will be roughly the same

**EDIT**

Ah I forgot that Vb.Net added iterator support in the latest version (Visual Studio 2012).  If you are using that version of Visual Studio you can do the following

```
Public Iterator Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerable(Of String) _ 
    Implements IEnumerable(Of String).GetEnumerator
   Yield Dma
   Yield Callsign
   Yield Description 
End Function
```